# ASPxColorEdit custom colors

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, color-picker

I'm using the latest ASPxEditor controls of devexpress.As you know this control has pre-defined colors.In my case I need to change [these colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHulN.png) and put my custom palette into this [control](http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxeditorsdemos/ASPxColorEdit/Example.aspx).

Is it possible to do so ? What are the alternatives ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, at present, the ASPxColorEdit control does not offer such a functionality.

There is a corresponding request regarding this feature:

http://www.devexpress.com/issue=S33198

Comment: I presumed that wouldn't.Can you give some alternatives to ColorPicker ?

Comment: I think, no :( I am using this editor "as is". It allows typing custom HEX code or color Name within the input box. It's enough in the simple scenarios :)